# Removal of Zookeeper in New Kafka Version

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I heard that Kafka will remove Zookeeper in the upcoming version.

Up until now, Kafka uses Zookeeper for handling metadata, selecting Controller, and coordinating a broker and cluster topology.

I am curious about how Kafka will handle the roles of zookeeper without zookeeper.

I would like to know the logic inside Kafka with no zookeeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes a Kafka Improvement Proposal (KIP) was voted a few weeks ago to replace Zookeeper with a Quorum of Kafka Controllers: [KIP-500](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum).

This initial KIP was mostly to highlight the high level architecture of such a big change. At the moment, the details and exact implementation are still to be figured out. If you want to know more, I suggest you to follow the developer mailing list where details will be discussed: http://kafka.apache.org/contact

Finally, there was a session about it at the last Kafka Summit: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-san-francisco-2019/kafka-needs-no-keeper